# Python3 (Selenium) can't locate password box

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

my current problem is that Python can't locate my password box.

```
<input class="stylepwd" name="pws" size="12" maxlength="12" onkeypress="return stEnter(event,this);" autocomplete="off" type="password">
```

Thats all i tried to do, but it always say it cant locate that box

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name('pws')
element = driver.find_element_by_class_tag('stylepwd')
element = driver.find_element_by_id('') #Yea, thats obviously not working ^^'
element.send_keys('mypassword')
```

Maybe there's another way I can type in that password. As soon as the site is loading, the cursor is in the box. Can I do anything with this? (Thats the site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM7eE.jpg)

Python code: https://pastebin.com/3ydHwDkH

Comment: Can you try once by xpath as "//input[@class='stylepwd']"

Comment: Apologies, that's the Java style xpath, you need to convert it into Python style xpath.

Comment: Is it inside an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="stylepwd"]')
```

This will give you the element `input` with `class="stylepwd"`

Comment: Im getting the error "Unable to locate element: //input[@class="stylepwd"]"

Comment: If your password box is something like you mentioned in the question, then this code should work. If you can add the url of the website to the question, it may be more clear.

Comment: I could, but its the site from my telekomrooter (https://speedport.ip/top_start_passwort.stm) so i dont think this will help
I updated the main post with the full source code from the site, maybe this helps

Comment: The said input element exists in the source code so the above code should have worked. Can you add your code in the pastebin as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in iframe, try

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0]
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
```

then

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name('pws')
```

Comment: If I use this then I get following error in that line with iframe = ... : IndexError: list index out of range